# Ограничение работы скрипта

Tags: javascript

Господа знатоки, подскажите пожалуйста. Есть скрипт, подвешен на кнопку, но некоторые пользователи жмут на нее несколько раз, видимо думают что это ярлык, в итоге скрипт выполняется несколько раз, есть ли возможность поставить ограничение, на количество нажатий или таймаута работы или проверку запущен ли скрипт?

Вот код:

```js
display += "<a id = 'sss"+id+"' title='запрос' onClick=\"var xap = new XMLHttpRequest();xap.open('GET', 'https://test', true);xap.send(null);\" class='btn grey order' style='text-decoration: none; padding:2px 3px; font-size: 13px;'><font color='black'>запрос</font></a>";
```

Comment: Есть возможность! Можно поставить ограничение на количество нажатий, или таймаут работы или проверять запущен ли скрипт. А что из этого у вас не получается и что вы пробовали.

Comment: при клике делаешь кнопку disabled, по окончании работы - enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте булевый флаг

```js
let flag = true; // Булевый флаг

document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(flag === true) { // При нажатие выполняем проверку флага
    flag = false; // Ставим false, чтобы не выполнялся код при нажатие
    // Выполням ваш код
    console.info('click');
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Допустим ваш код выполнился, меняем флаг обратно на true, это нужно делать в конце, когда ваш код выполнится
      flag = true;
    }, 2000)
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Жать можно только раз в 2 секунды</button>
```

---

[@Алексей Шиманский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1334075/%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0/1334080?noredirect=1#comment2360142_1334075) подсказал ещё один интересный способ, использовать [атрибут `disabled`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/disabled).
Этот способ будет даже лучше, чем первый, т.к. не требует записывать ничего в переменную.

```js
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.disabled === false) { // проверяем наличие disabled
    e.target.disabled = true; // Активируем disabled
    // Выполням ваш код
    console.info('click');
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Допустим ваш код выполнился, disabled на false, это нужно делать в конце, когда ваш код выполнится
      e.target.disabled = false;
    }, 2000)
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Жать можно только раз в 2 секунды</button>
```

Comment: Увы, почему то не видит flag, пробовал и через var объявлять, видит только если вставить в сам скрипт который по клику отрабатывает))

Comment: @Влад, отредактируйте ваш вопрос, добавив туда код вашей попытки, либо выложите на [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Добавил пример кода

Comment: @Влад, посмотрел ваш код, если я правильно понял, вам нужно запретить клик по кнопке, пока выполняется AJAX запрос. Если так, то нужно переписывать так, чтобы "разрешение нажатия" ставилось когда запрос выполнился. Чтобы точнее решить этот вопрос, нужно больше кода.

Comment: Если добавить в onClick="this.setAttribute('disabled', true);" то кнопка после клика отключается, но вот активировать ее обратно таким же образом не получается, ибо он не может после этого его найти, надо как то получать id кнопки, а он всегда уникальный. На счет кода не знаю что еще можно дать...

Comment: @Влад, желательно выполнять `onclick` не в теле тега, а в скрипте. Либо так `onClick="var _self = this; _self.disabled = true; setTimeout(function(){ _self.disabled = false }, 2000)"`

Comment: Благодарю, это то что надо, все работает!!!